# reuse typescript interface inside another interface

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to **re-use pre defined interface** inside another interface?

Example:

```
interface details_ {
    id: number,
    name: string
}

interface amount_{
    amount: number,
    type: string
}

interface api_data{
    details: details_,
    amount: amount_,
}
```

How do I reuse the predefined interface (here: details_) inside another interface api_Data.details ?

Comment: What do you mean with reusing? , you mean achieve what your example show?, if so, just the way you did should be enough. Or maybe you are referring to inheritance in your interfaces?

Comment: well I was not very sure about the interface inheritance, got them cleared now!

Answer (score 0):

```
    interface Name {
        fisrtName:string;
        lastName:string;
    }
    
    interface Address {
        street:string;
        city:string;
    }
    
    interface Person{
        name:Name;
        address: Address;
    }
    
    let person:Person = {
        name:{
            fisrtName: "User",
            lastName: "User"
        },
        address:{
            street: "ABC",
            city: "XYZ"
        }
    };
    
    console.log(person)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much the point of types and interfaces - to define the type of data and to be used to define other types and interfaces ("re-use them").

You've already written how this is done in your example - it actually looks correct. Did you encounter any problems compiling that code?

For another example, let's simply consider something like this:

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface Foo {
  x: string;
  y: number;
  person: Person;
}
```

Foo is now a type that has `x`, `y` and `person`, where `person` in turn has `name` and `age`.

```
const myFoo: foo = {x: 'hello', y: 42, person: {name: 'Joe', age: 33}};
```

Comment: what if I want inherit only the name property from the Person interface?
will it be 
interface Foo { 
  x: string,
  name: Person.name
}

Comment: Then you could do `name: Person['name'] ;`